# semantic-ui hide element for mobile view

Tags: semantic-ui, responsive

I am looking for semantic-ui the correct class to hide for example a DIV in mobile view. In Bootstrap its easy there we have "visible-xs" and "hidden-xs".

But on semantic ui I only found "mobile only grid"

Answer (score 3):

Please visit here just add to your override css file

```
/* Mobile */

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
[class*="mobile hidden"],
[class*="tablet only"]:not(.mobile),
[class*="computer only"]:not(.mobile),
[class*="large monitor only"]:not(.mobile),
[class*="widescreen monitor only"]:not(.mobile),
[class*="or lower hidden"] {
display: none !important;
}
}
etc...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8LkLoxcx/