# semantic-ui: how to hide element on mobile only?

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I need to hide some element, e.g. an image, only on mobile. How can I achive this with semantic-ui?

Is there anything like "hide-xs" in angular material or "hidden-xs" in bootstrap?

I read through the documentation and couldn´t find anything similar. All I found were [some options for a grid](https://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html#device-visibility), but I don´t want to use a grid, just to make an element invisible on certain devices...

```
<div class="ui grid">
  <div class="two column mobile only row">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="ui segment">
        Mobile only
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also I found [some solution here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41683267/semantic-ui-hide-element-for-mobile-view), where someone suggested to write some additional CSS. Like this:

```
/* Mobile */

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  [class*="mobile hidden"],
  [class*="tablet only"]:not(.mobile),
  [class*="computer only"]:not(.mobile),
  [class*="large monitor only"]:not(.mobile),
  [class*="widescreen monitor only"]:not(.mobile),
  [class*="or lower hidden"] {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Is that really the way to go? Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to either use `grid` or override the styles. That's the only way to go in Semantic UI. 
It is evident in the `mobile only` class definition.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  .ui[class*="mobile only"].grid.grid.grid:not(.tablet),
  .ui.grid.grid.grid > [class*="mobile only"].row:not(.tablet),
  .ui.grid.grid.grid > [class*="mobile only"].column:not(.tablet),
  .ui.grid.grid.grid > .row > [class*="mobile only"].column:not(.tablet) {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) and (min-width: 992px) {
  .ui[class*="mobile only"].grid.grid.grid:not(.computer),
  .ui.grid.grid.grid > [class*="mobile only"].row:not(.computer),
  .ui.grid.grid.grid > [class*="mobile only"].column:not(.computer),
  .ui.grid.grid.grid > .row > [class*="mobile only"].column:not(.computer) {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1919px) and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .ui[class*="mobile only"].grid.grid.grid:not(.computer),
  .ui.grid.grid.grid > [class*="mobile only"].row:not(.computer),
  .ui.grid.grid.grid > [class*="mobile only"].column:not(.computer),
  .ui.grid.grid.grid > .row > [class*="mobile only"].column:not(.computer) {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
  .ui[class*="mobile only"].grid.grid.grid:not(.computer),
  .ui.grid.grid.grid > [class*="mobile only"].row:not(.computer),
  .ui.grid.grid.grid > [class*="mobile only"].column:not(.computer),
  .ui.grid.grid.grid > .row > [class*="mobile only"].column:not(.computer) {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.